# How do we know orbits go in an elliptic shape?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, history, solar-system

I never really understood how we found out the orbits our planets follow are elliptical and not in a circle.

Comment: Do you mean what is the observational evidence that they move in ellipses?

Comment: Yes, how do we know it goes in that way?

Comment: This question might be better suited for the HSM stackexchange. You might be interested in the answers here: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3575/how-did-newton-and-kepler-actually-do-it

Comment: Also [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5482/how-did-kepler-make-his-discovery?rq=1) and [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/1948/how-did-kepler-guess-his-third-law-from-data?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

With a triangular sextant (https://www.sciencesource.com/archive/Image/Tycho-Brahe--Triangular-Sextant--1582-SS21473734.html) and a lot of patience.

Answer (score 1):

From a mathematical/philosophical standpoint, we can conclude that all orbits are eccentric *to some extent*, without needing to do any observation at all.

A truly perfectly circular orbit (eccentricity equal to *exactly* zero) at some orbital radius requires an *exact* orbital speed with infinite precision. Velocities are continuous, so the probability of a body having any particular velocity is zero - the chance of picking any particular value from a continuum of values is always zero. The probability that any body has exactly the orbital speed needed to have an orbit with an eccentricity of exactly zero is, in fact, zero. Any body in orbit *almost surely* does not have the correct velocity to be in a *perfect* circular orbit, the probability that it does is 0. *All* orbits are eccentric to varying degrees. The probability of finding an orbiting body with *any exact* eccentricity value is zero, whether that value is $0.0128475000...$ or $0.00000000...$ . You will *almost never* find a body with an orbital eccentricity of precisely zero.

Comment: I would remove the "*almost*".   Any perturbation from Newton's Law as applied to a planet will wreck a circular orbit, and a perturbation-free situation never occurs.

Comment: A truly perfectly elliptical orbit also requires an exact (position dependent) velocity with infinite precision. Nothing in this answer gives any reason why we say orbits are elliptical. Keep in mind, people in Kepler's time didn't know Newton's law of gravitation, so for all they knew, it might have been the case that circular orbits were the only possibility. Determining the shapes of orbits requires empirical observation.

Comment: From a mathematical/philosophical standpoint, we cannot conclude that all orbits are eccentric, because mathematics and philosophy can't even tell us how many parameters it takes to describe an orbit, let alone the probabilities with which the values of those parameters occur in the physical world.